# conception and syntax errors in OOP. Are non virtual methods in daughter classes that are redefined from the mother class masked?

Tags: c++, class, oop, polymorphism, virtual

For an example, we were given sample code where we had to find its errors and give explanations as to why there were errors. The questions I have are numbered 1-5.

#### First part

We had a class, `Flight`, declared as follows:

```
class Flight {
public:
~Flight(){for(auto & b: places) delete b; }
....
..
private: 
vector<unique_ptr<Bill>>places; //bill is a previously declared class
};
```

I said that is because `b` is a unique_ptr and we can't delete them, they are deleted by default. So my suggestion was that we could either change the attribute and take normal points in C, `vector<Bill*>places;` or just remove the destructor. However, someone suggested that we write instead `b.reset();`

1. Can someone explain to me what is the purpose of that as opposed to just removing the destructor? Which is better to do, and why?

#### Second part

There are other conceptual mistakes, and I am not sure if I am right. The rest of the code is as follows:

```
class Sell {
public: 
virtual ~ Sell(){}
virtual double price() const = 0; 
protected: 
double base_price; 
}; 

class Bill : public Sell {
public: 
Bill(int id, double price, string name, bool vegetarian) etc{}
virtual ~Bill()

{}
virtual ostream& display(ostream& out) const 
out << "no. " << id << " for " << name << endl; return out; 
}

double price() const{
if(vegetarian) { return base_price() - 20; }
 else { return base_price(); }
}

private: int id; string name; bool vegetarian; 
}; 

ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Bill& bill){ return bill.display(out); }

class Business : public Bill {
public: Business(int id, double base_price.........)etc
virtual ~Business() { ~Bill(); }

ostream& display(ostream& out ) const {
out << "business "; 
Bill::display(out); 
if (extra_space){ out << "with supplementary space. " ; }
return out; 
}

double price() {
double p(Bill::price()); 
if(extra_space) { p*= 1.5; }
return p; 
}

private: bool extra_space; 
}; 

//then there is class Flight as defined above. 
class Flight {
    public:
    ~Flight(){for(auto & b: places) delete b; }
    void sold(Bill* b){ places.push_back(unique_ptr<Bill>(b)); }
    void display() const {
for(auto const& b: places){cout << "The Bill " << *b << "is " << b->price() << "Dollars. " << endl; 
}}

    ..
    private: 
    vector<unique_ptr<Bill>>places; //bill is a previously declared class
    }; 

int main(){
Flight f1; 
f1.sold(new Bill(1,100,"Chopin", true)); 
f1.sold(new Business(2, 100, "Sand, false, true)): 
f1.display() << endl; 
return 0; 
}
```

2. There is a warning that says `virtual double Bill::price() const` was hidden. I suggested this is masking and that the price function in the bill class should be virtual. Does this make sense?
3. There was also a warning by `double Business::price() [Woverloaded-virtual]`. This, I don't understand, is this because there is no `const` in the `price()` class defined in `business`?
4. Also, is `price()` considered as the same function in all the classes? Because I don't understand how if there is a missing `const` in the price of business, that it would compile. I would have thought it would not only display a warning but a compilation error...
5. Finally, for the `main()` function, there is a problem with `(new Business)`, is this because we can only create an address for bill?

Comment: I made a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/sbolel/c5502a42f29e1b2e6b07) with your code, and slightly improved the code formatting. I also added some comments that may help. If you look at the `main()` function, my comment might address your last question with the error in `new Business()`.

Comment: (i) you don't need the destructor, so drop it (otherwise you'd probably would have to consider the rule of three/five) (ii) use `virtual` in front of any polymorphic function (not just in the base class), and in addition, use `override`. That should avoid your overloading ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all classes, if they are written in c++11 or better and are designed properly will not have user-defined destructors, user-defined copy operators or user-defined move operators.

There is a very good reason for this, which is that if you don't define any of these, the compiler will generate correct versions for you.

In your case, the vector of `Bill` is managing the lifetime of the bills through std::unique_ptr (good!!). This means that lifetimes will be correctly managed automatically and your first intuition was correct - simply remove the destructor and let the compiler do the right thing.

Your friend's suggestion to replace delete with .reset() was also correct, but convoluted and un-necessary.